# Class with pass-by-reference object gives compile error

Tags: c++, oop, class, object, pass-by-reference

I've got a class A defined in a separate header file. I want class B to have a reference to a object of class A stored as a variable.

Like this:

#### File: A.h

```
class A {
    //Header for class A...
};
```

#### File: B.h

```
#include "A.h"
class B {
    private:
(24)        A &variableName;
    public:
(36)        B(A &varName);
};
```

When i try to compile it with g++ I get the following error:

```
B.h:24: error: ‘A’ does not name a type
B.h:36: error: expected `)' before ‘&’ token
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong? If it matters, the class A is an abstract class.

EDIT: Some typos in the code

Comment: I think you mistyped the class names. Class B has a B& member and a constructor A().

Comment: You're missing semicolons after the class definition. `class A { ... }; //<-- here`.

Comment: Definatly some typos when I quickly wrote the code in here at SO! :)

Comment: are you including B.h in A.h?

Comment: No, I'm not including B.h in A.h

Comment: You write here, that the error is reported in A.h, not in B.h. That a typo too?

Comment: this is most probably caused by circularly including the files..Is A.h does `#include` of any other file which may internally does a `#include "B.h"`?

Comment: Space_cowboy: Yup that's another typo... :| 100% sure it's correct now!

Comment: Naven: A.h does not include any files

Comment: This is probably a typo, define or similar problem. If you type it into stackoverflow and make even more typos this is not going to help really. Try to reduce your code to the minimum expression that fails and then just copy and paste into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By me it compiles fine (as expected).  I'm guessing `A.h` isn't being included properly.  Is there another file with the same name that gets included instead?  Perhaps there are `#ifdef`s or some such that prevent the definition of `A` from being seen by the compiler.  To check this, I would put some sort of syntax error into `A.h` and see if the compiler catches it.

Comment: That's it! I've got some #ifndef-s that wasn't correct. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Paul: thats why it is always better to copy paste the code from editor while asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

Does A.h include B.h (directly or indirectly)?  If so, then you wouldn't be able to define A before B because of the recursive inclusions.  If B needs to be defined in A, use a [forward declaration](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.12).

Answer (score 0):

You appear to try and declare a constructor for class A inside a completely unrelated class B, which is what the compiler is complaining about.

If you want to have default/implicit way of turning a `B` into an `A` from the compiler's perspective, you'll need something like

```
operator A(B const &var);
```

instead of a constructor declaration.

Answer (score 0):

For all I can see, this code is correct. Check the following please:

- is A in some namespace?
- is A a nested class?
- is A the name of some macro in your code?
- is A really named A, or is there some typo in your real code?

If none of these work, well then I cannot help you unless you post the real code where the error happens.

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo when I changed the names. It's correct now

Comment: Edit: Added list of potential causes.

Answer (score -2):

Note that having references as member variables is seldomly a good idea. What does the name B really stand for?

Comment: Why is it a bad idea? There's nothing wrong with having references as member variables.

Comment: B is a logger. The plan is that it's going to get values from A (which drives a motor connected to the usb) for storage and processing.